# Rendering process failed null

Tags: geoserver, rendering

In GeoServer, I published a polygon shapefile with default polygon SLD, while in preview when I click on feature it shows the error rendering process failed null.

Please explain what is this error, what I have yo do to overcome this error?

Comment: We had a couple of similar problems while setting up our GeoServer, mostly caused by Java and Tomcat configuration problems. After checking this (thankfully I had an IT colleague for this) - will a simple shapefile with just a number of polygons render? Maybe your data is corrupted...

Comment: You need to publish the exact error message and the log file extract relating to the error in your question .. Thanks ..